# Emacs slime mini buffer take-over

Tags: emacs, buffer, slime

For no obvious reason firing up slime in Emacs produces this message in the mini buffer:

> Polling "/tmp/slime.5000 .. 25 (Abort with `M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) [730 times]

That [730 times] keeps growing. Supposedly, this means slime had trouble starting, but no, it's working fine.

Here's my Messages buffer starting with slime initialization:

> ../../quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/slime-20130217-cvs/contrib/slime-package-fu.el:
>   `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either`cl-flet' or
>   `cl-letf'. [4 times] Starting Emacs daemon. When done with this frame,
>   type C-x 5 0 Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 1 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 2 (Abort with
>   `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 3 (Abort
>   with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 4
>   (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080"
>   .. 5 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 6 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 7 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 8 (Abort with
>   `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 9 (Abort
>   with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 10
>   (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080"
>   .. 11 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 12 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 13 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 14 (Abort with
>   `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 15 (Abort
>   with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 16
>   (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080"
>   .. 17 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 18 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 19 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 20 (Abort with
>   `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 21 (Abort
>   with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 22
>   (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling "/tmp/slime.5080"
>   .. 23 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.) Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 24 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) Connecting to Swank on port 39808.. Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) [2
>   times] Source file`
>   /home/lawrence/.emacs.d/elpa/clojure-mode-1.11.5/clojure-mode.el'
>   newer than byte-compiled file Connected. Let the hacking commence!
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with `M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) [297 times] Mark set Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   [207 times] Mark saved where search started Polling "/tmp/slime.5080"
>   .. 25 (Abort with `M-x slime-abort-connection'.) [58 times] Cancelled
>   connection attempt. Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) [1159 times] byte-code: Beginning of buffer
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with `M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) [2 times] byte-code: Beginning of buffer [2
>   times] Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with`M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) [2 times] byte-code: Beginning of buffer
>   Polling "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with `M-x
>   slime-abort-connection'.) byte-code: Beginning of buffer Polling
>   "/tmp/slime.5080" .. 25 (Abort with`M-x slime-abort-connection'.)
>   [202 times]

Comment: killing the emacs daemon and restarting seemed to clear it up. Still curious, though, why...

Answer (score 1):

Clean out your .cache/common-lisp/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Alex Thornton -- At your earliest convenience, please add a detailed comment explaining why you believe this answer does not resolve the issue of the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

after install emacs 24.3，i have the same problem，you can do like this

```
cd /path/slime/contrib
find ./ -name '*.elc' | xargs rm -f
```

then,restart your emacs

Comment: what does this do and why should I do it? I haven't had this problem lately -- maybe due to changing over to a quicklisp install of slime.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite polling may be due to the missing of file `swank-loader.lisp`. Check the variable `slime-backend` to see whether it contains the right path to `swank-loader.lisp`.

On my computer I don't even have a `swank-loader.lisp` file(I noticed that if you install the *slime* using elpa, this may happen). So I downloaded the entire *slime* from [here](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/#downloading) and got it right.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that there wasn't a /tmp folder in my .emacs.d/ folder.  Adding the /tmp folder solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred on my Emacs + Slime + CCL/SBCL/CLISP/ECL，and I had  a solution, On my system, it is ok! you can try.

The reason of the error maybe the versions of slime and swank are mismatch. So the solution is to use the same version slime and swank.

My system is Raspbian(one kind of debian). I installed slime with the command "apt-get install slime"，then slime and emacs will be installed automatically to the path "/usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/". But I think the version is not the newest one.

The solution:
1、Get the newest slime to your home path:
command:

cd ~/
sudo git clone  https://github.com/slime/slime slime
cd slime 
make

2、Add tmp path and load-path in ~/.emacs:

(setq temporary-file-directory "/tmp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/pi/slime/")

3、Rename the /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/ to /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime-back/
command:

sudo mv /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime/ /usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime-back/

4、Use the newest slime to create a symbol link 
command:

sudo ln -s /home/pi/slime //usr/share/common-lisp/source/slime

5、Remove the cache and temp files
command:

sudo mv ~/.cache/common-lisp ~/.cache/common-lisp-back

OK, now you can try to start emacs and slime.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Debian 10, installing the `cl-swank` package fixed the issue.

```
This package contains the Lisp-side server, needed by the Emacs client (see package slime).
```

(My `slime` is also from the Debian repo.)